# Illustrator pattern swatch: graphic appears three times

Tags: adobe-illustrator, patterns, brush, swatches

I have artwork of a locomotive and a wagon, and I want to create a pattern brush out of it:
[image: Locomotive Artwork]
[image: Wagon Artwork]

First, I create a pattern swatch using "Object > Pattern > Make". Then I get a pattern swatch that contains the artwork three times stacked, e.g. like this:

[image: Locomotive Pattern Swatch]

Although my pattern settings are correct, and my pattern shows the artwork only once:
[image: Illustrator pattern settings]

Therefore, the pattern brush created out of these pattern swatches looks ugly as well:
[image: Illustrator pattern brush settings]

Any Ideas how to get only a single row of locomotives and wagons?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is not necessary to create a pattern to get a pattern brush.

Create a **Pattern Brush** dragging the wagon to the **Brush Panel**

Select the locomotive and pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd> drag it to the brush modules, the first on the right

[image: train]

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works that way. But do you have an idea why the pattern always showed the artwork three times?

Comment: @LukeLR We are talking about two different things: Pattern and Pattern Brush. A Pattern is used to fill shapes, when you create one there is a panel with options, change those options to get different results.

Comment: I thought the settings of my pattern were correct. Especially since the preview exposed only a single occurence of the artwork. But as it works equally well without creating a pattern, I'll use the pattern brush without the pattern :)